# I have 10 Php files . when I inlude one by one each one works correctly but when i write them in " if " condition some part of it does not work

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

Below code work correctly when i include 'piechart.php' individually

```
    include 'header.php';

    include 'connection.php';

    include 'piechart.php';
```

but , when I write following code it does not full work

```
{
        include 'header.php';


        include 'connection.php';

        // checking which chart is to be shown
        $selectQuery     = "SELECT * FROM `emi_content_table` WHERE status= 1 ";
        $fireSelectQuery = mysqli_query($connection,$selectQuery);
        $gotChart        = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fireSelectQuery);
        $gotChartName    = $gotChart['chart_name'];
        $selectQuery2     = "SELECT * FROM `emi_content_table2` WHERE status= 1 ";
        $fireSelectQuery2 = mysqli_query($connection,$selectQuery2);
        $gotChart2        = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fireSelectQuery2);
        $gotChartName2    = $gotChart2['chart_name'];
        if($gotChartName == 'pie chart'){
            include 'piechart.php';
        }
        if($gotChartName == 'Pie chart with legend'){
            include 'Piechartwithlegend.php';
        }
        if($gotChartName == '3D pie'){
            include '3Dpie.php';
        }
        if($gotChartName == 'Styled pie'){
            include 'Styledpie.php';
        }
        if($gotChartName == 'Semi circle donut'){
            include 'Semicircledonut.php';
        }
        // bar chart
        if($gotChartName2 == 'Basic Bar'){
            include 'BasicBarchart.php';
        }
        if($gotChartName2 == 'Stacked Column'){
            include 'StackedColumn.php';
        }
        if($gotChartName2 == 'Basic Column'){
            include 'BasiccolumnBarchart.php';
        }
        if($gotChartName2 == 'Stacked and grouped column'){
            include 'GroupedColumnBarchart.php';
        }
        if($gotChartName2 == '3D Column'){
            include '3DBarchart.php';
        }

}
```

Below is my page where `piechart` is display :

[image]

when i drag the `range slider` and change the position then the `piechart's function` is called each time and this piechart's code is written in `Jquery`.
when the file  of this piechart is included individually it works good and the piechart's function is called .
but the `problem` is when i include all the files like the above code using `"if" conditions` then it does `not call` the piechart function

Comment: Is the parchart.php ever loaded? And is the chart name "pie chart" (with small starting letter), rather Than "Pie chart" (with capital "P")?

Comment: Can you echo the `$gotChartName` to make sure your queries are executed properly?

Comment: JavaScript files are often cached client-side. I'm not sure if the caching is the issue here, but seems like it.

Comment: You've used `highcharts` tag but your issue is not strictly related to it.